# Reactive Form, disable form control after ngOnChanges don't changes the template

Tags: angular

I am working with reactive forms on an Angular 7 project.
In some component I have a form built with a FormBuilder, and I need some controls to be disabled or enabled depending on an input property.

This input property is obtained in the parent component from an asynchronous request, and when its value changes, I change the "disabled" status, but the template is not changed as expected: the `disabled` attribute is not set on the corresponding `<input>`.

Here is my code:

```
@Input() myInputProperty;
form: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (changes['myInputProperty']) {
    this.buildForm();
  }
}

private buildForm() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    myControl: {value: myInputProperty && myInputPropery.stuff, disabled: !!myInputProperty}
  });
}
```

We go twice in the method buildForm(), one time when `myInputProperty` is not set and one time when `myInputProperty` has been requested ; after the second time the control is disabled but the template is not updated, the `disabled` attribute is set on the `<input>`.

I tried with `this.form.get('myControl').disable()` but it doesn't work better.

If I add some code like

```
  if (this.myInputProperty) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.form.get('myControl').disable();
    });
  }
```

at the end of `buildForm()`, it works but it is not a satisfying workaround.

EDIT: example on stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rkurxt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: I made some changes that work around the problem in my case (when making a request I only load the component after the response, so the component is directly created with the final value of myInputProperty), but that doesn't solves the background problem.

Comment: can you create stackblitz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rkurxt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: Hey .. did you find the problem. I am facing similar issue. I looked at the stackblitz example and I don't understand why we need setTimeout

Comment: I didn't solved the problem...